# Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache throws OutOfMemoryException when add many item to cache

Tags: c#, .net, caching

For some heavy calculation I want to to put temp results to MemoryCache and load it again when required.
But when I put 2 million object to Cache, it throws OutOfMemoryException.

I run program on windows 7 64 bit with 8GB ram.

When I look to task manager I see that my application take only 1.5 GB ram and then crash.
This code is similar to what I do in my program

```
NameValueCollection config = new NameValueCollection
{
    {"cacheMemoryLimitMegabytes", "4000"},
    {"physicalMemoryLimitPercentage", "100"}
};
MemoryCache cache = new MemoryCache("MyCache", config);
CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy { AbsoluteExpiration = ObjectCache.InfiniteAbsoluteExpiration };
for (int i = 0; i < 4000000; i++)
{
    var resultOfTempOperation = DoOperation();
    CacheItem newEmployee = new CacheItem(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), new SomeClass());
    cache.Add(newEmployee, policy);
}
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Setting the memory limit to 4000 megabytes in a 32-bit process is not useful.  Remove the jitter forcing.

Answer (score 4):

In visual studio go to

Solution>Properties>Configuration Properties>Platform

Make sure you are compiling for x64 if you need to use so much memory. (You are hitting the 32bit limit)

Answer (score 0):

You've specified a memory limit but not when it should poll to trim the cache.  You can do that by adding:

```
NameValueCollection config = new NameValueCollection
{
    {"cacheMemoryLimitMegabytes", "4000"},
    {"physicalMemoryLimitPercentage", "100"},
    {"pollingInterval", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5).ToString()}
};
```

That will instruct the CLR to look for objects to evict every 5 minutes in you cache.